# Copy table to Outlook mail body inside a loop

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have two dictionaries `workerDict` and `managerDict`.

I loop through every teamID of workers to get the manager of that team, then I send email to all members of a team and their managers in cc.

I want to add a table that has info about that team.

Table structure:

```json
Name | LastName | TeamID | Tasks
```

I tried to sort on TeamID of each team and copy that table and send it, so that each team will get only the info related to it using teamID.

```vb
For Each teamID In workerDict.keys
    Call REFiltreTable("clr") 'clear sort after iteration
    workerEmail = workerDict(teamID)
    managerEmail = managerDict(teamID)
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    Call REFiltreTable("sort", teamID) 'just does simple sort on table
    
    With outlookMail
        .To = workerEmail
        .CC = managerEmail
        .Subject = "REMINDER ACTIJET - " & actiMonth & " " & actiYear
        
        DoEvents ' Allows time for the signature to be added
        
        Dim wDoc As Object
        Set wDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        Dim rng As Object
        Set rng = wDoc.Range(0, 0)
        
        rng.Text = mailBodyFR
        rng.InsertAfter vbNewLine
        
        With rng.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 12
            .Color = RGB(31, 73, 125)
        End With
        
        tbl.Range.Copy 'tbl is ListObject is my table
        rng.Collapse 0 ' Collapse to the end of the document
        rng.Paste

        .Display
    End With
Next teamID
```

`rng.Paste` is where I get an error

> Word has encountered a problem

Sometimes 1 or 2 emails out of 10 generate.

I want to keep using my doc range object because I get my Outlook signature automatically.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)